# When should I use setUserState in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, session-variables, session-state, joomla2.5

**DETAILS**

I can use user state variables to store and retrieve data in Joomla sessions.

**EXAMPLE set variable**

```
$app =& JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setUserState( 'myvar', $myvarvalue );
```

but I can also store and retrieve variables in session using JFactory/getSession.

**EXAMPLE set variable**

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('myvar', $myvarvalue);
```

**QUESTIONs**

What is the difference between the two methods?
When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In short:** it's not a big difference and you can use whatever feels right in the context. I would stick with  `JApplication/setUserState` because I think the code is better self explanatory.

**The actual difference:**

Both methods will store the specified state in the session. `JApplication/setUserState` will in fact internally use `JSession/set` to store the state.

What `JApplication/setUserState` does differently is that it will store every key value pair in a [JRegistry](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Registry/JRegistry.html). So it is equal to:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$registry = $session->get('registry');
$registry->set('myvar', $myvarvalue);
```

So what's the point of using a `JRegistry`? It's the pretty much the functionally provided `JRegistryFormat`. You can use it to both parse and format the state:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$registry = $session->get('registry');
$json = $registry->toString('JSON');
$xml = $registry->toString('XML');
```

It's also worth pointing out that using `JApplication/setUserState` your state will end up in the "default" namespace:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setUserState( 'myvar', $myvarvalue );
// $_SESSION['default']['registry']->set('myvar', $myvarvalue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I feel I understand the differences/similarities now :)